# How to write a recursive function that returns a list of numbers that count down from n to 0?

Tags: python

I am having trouble with this seemingly simple function.

```py
def countdown(n: int):
    """
    Write a simple recursive function that returns a list of numbers that count down from n.

    countdown(5) -> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    countdown(8) -> [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    countdown(-1) -> []

    :param n: start
    :return: countdown sequence
    """
    print([n])
    if n >= 1:
        countdown(n - 1)
```

My output:

```
[5]
[4]
[3]
[2]
[1]
[0]
None
```

Expected output:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Is there a simple pythonic way to improve my solution, or should I start from scratch?

EDIT: Got it working, using a few bits from the answers below

```
def countdown(n: int, nums=None):
    """
    Write a simple recursive function that returns a list of numbers that count down from n.

    countdown(5) -> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    countdown(8) -> [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    countdown(-1) -> []

    :param n: start
    :return: countdown sequence
    """
    if nums is None:
        nums = []
    if n >= 0:
        nums.append(n)
        return countdown(n - 1, nums)
    else:
        return nums
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I shall edit my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
def countdown(n:int):
    integers = []
    if n>=1:
        for i in range(n+1):
            integers.append(n-i)
    return integers

countdown(6)
```

Output: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

Answer (score 2):

You are very nearly there. You are getting `None` because you don't return anything in the function. You can do something like this:

```
def countdown(n, nums=[]):
    nums = nums.copy()
    if n >= 0:
        nums.append(n)
        return countdown(n-1, nums)
    else:
        return nums

result = countdown(5)
```

Which outputs:

```
[5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

As the comments noted, recursion is not encouraged here. A simpler alternative is simply just reversing a range, like so:

```
n=5
result = list(range(0,n+1))[::-1]
```

**OR**

```
n=5
result = list(range(0,n+1))
result.reverse()
```

Which outputs:

```
[5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

Comment: The solution works for the input n = 5, however, if I call out print(countdown(8)) after print(countdown(5)), the output is [5,4,3,2,1,0,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]. The fix is to pass nums = none into argument instead of nums =[]

Comment: Actually, `None` will not work because you cannot use `.append()` on `None`.  Thank you for catching the mistake - it is because of list mutability. This is one of the reasons why you should not use recursion for such a problem as it can overcomplicate something so simple. Using `.copy()` will solve the issue. If you want to use `None`, you can write an if statement that sets `nums` to an empty list if it is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Recursive Solution

Given that the brief is

> Write a simple recursive function that returns a list of numbers that count down from n.

The most obvious issue with your code is that you're not actually returning anything, you're simply printing each value counting down from `n...0` in its own `list` with each call to `countdown()`. To remedy this you could use `list.append()` to add each value `n...0` to an empty `list` passed to `countdown()` when it is first called.

```py
def countdown(n: int, l: list):
    if n >= 0:
        l.append(n)
        countdown(n - 1, l)
    return(l)

print(countdown(5, []))
print(countdown(8, []))
```

**Output**

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

If you absolutely must use recursion to write this function because this is a homework assignment or something similar, then the above solution provides the functionality that you're looking for using recursion.

#### Non-Recursive Solution

If solutions not using recursion are acceptable - which honestly they should be as this is not a strong practical case for using recursive functions - then the following provides the same output without relying on recursive calls to `countdown()`.

```py
def countdown(n: int):
    return [i for i in range(n+1)][::-1] if n >= 0 else []

print(countdown(5))
print(countdown(8))
```

**Output**

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for.

```
def countdown(n: int, nums=None):

    if nums is None:
        nums = []
    if n >= 0:
        nums.append(n)
        return countdown(n - 1, nums)
    else:
        return nums
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
my_list = []

if n == -1:
    return []
if n >= 0:
    my_list.append(n)
    return my_list + countdown(n - 1)
```